# SAPUI5 bind View to Wizardstep

Tags: url-routing, sapui5

i dynamically add steps to a wizard. For each step i have a corresponding view which should be bound at runtime.

can anyone tell me the best way to achieve it please?
with fragment i could used the following code:

```
sap.ui.xmlfragment("firstapp.flightdata.view." + wa[j].getAttribute("value"), this).placeAt(wa[j].getAttribute("id"));
```

wa[j] is the current step.
should i work with routing? If yes how please
Thanks in advance.

Aline

Answer (score 0):

was pretty easy.

```
nestedView = sap.ui.xmlview('firstapp.flightdata.view.Street');
this.getView().byId("page1").addContent(nestedView);
```

or

```
sap.ui.xmlview('firstapp.flightdata.view.Street').placeAt(this.getView().byId("page1"));
```